# Get User timezone to show the correct time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I want to be able to show the correct time for every user depending on their timezones, and also be able to store all time records in my database in UTC.

Any thoughts of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post on timezones with rails, you can read it here: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

also be sure to watch the rails cast on timezones: http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised

Comment: Great blog post, very helpful.. So I need to do something like this in the application controller:

    around_filter :user_time_zone, if: :current_user

    private

    def user_time_zone(&block)
      Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
    end

But how do I get the time_zone from a user? That's my main deal. I'm not able to see the video. Don't have the rights to.

Comment: you need to add a `time_zone` column to your users and allow them to edit it - if you are doing rails development you should pay for 'rails cast pro', it doesn't cost much and there is so much information there; here is old rails 2 version of that episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1 obviously it is older (but free to watch)

Comment: When you say '...and allow them to edit it ..." who are "them"? I've got a time_zone column already, but don't know how to handle the time zone getter and posting it to its user yet. No clue without watching that video then. Can you give me that answer if you know it? Tanks :)

Comment: your users have a form where they can edit their profile? password, etc... add time_zone edit option there - here is a link to a sample repo that went with the blog post: https://github.com/house9/sample_timez

Comment: Nope, anyway what I want to be able is to get the timezone without the user do anything. Do you know any way to implement this?

Comment: guessing you'll need to get it from the browser using javascript and then pass that to rails, maybe save it on the user so that you can use I18n in the views - you'll still want to give the user a way to change it